# How to run Rails-app automatically after restart production/staging server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, capistrano, puma

I deploy rails application with capistrano.
Use puma+nginx.
When I restart the server I need to start application automatically.
How to do it correctly?

Thx.

Comment: This is actually a very complex topic. Search for `rails puma init.d` for ways to accomplish this.

Comment: Thx. I understand and configure https://github.com/puma/puma/tree/master/tools/jungle/upstart

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to use the capistrano/puma integration as detailed [here](https://github.com/puma/puma#capistrano-deployment)